# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException decimal format

Tags: java, android, decimalformat

I want force two digits formats after decimal but my app getting crash when i log.

```
Log.v("log", new DecimalFormat("00.00").format("62.42"));
```

Answer (score 4):

It should do fine with you.

```
Log.v("log", new DecimalFormat("00.00").format(62.42));
```

But if you think you must to have String as input, then parse that into Double first, and then do operation:

```
Log.v("log", new DecimalFormat("00.00").format(Double.parseDouble("62.42")));
```

Answer (score 2):

`DecimalFormat` inherits `Format#format(Object)` which delegates to `DecimalFormat#format(Object, StringBuffer, FieldPosition)`. This is implemented as

```
public final StringBuffer format(Object number,
                                 StringBuffer toAppendTo,
                                 FieldPosition pos) {
    if (number instanceof Long || number instanceof Integer ||
               number instanceof Short || number instanceof Byte ||
               number instanceof AtomicInteger ||
               number instanceof AtomicLong ||
               (number instanceof BigInteger &&
                ((BigInteger)number).bitLength () < 64)) {
        return format(((Number)number).longValue(), toAppendTo, pos);
    } else if (number instanceof BigDecimal) {
        return format((BigDecimal)number, toAppendTo, pos);
    } else if (number instanceof BigInteger) {
        return format((BigInteger)number, toAppendTo, pos);
    } else if (number instanceof Number) {
        return format(((Number)number).doubleValue(), toAppendTo, pos);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot format given Object as a Number");
    }
}
```

So you see, you cannot pass a `String` argument.

The String `62.42` is already formatted the way you want it.